Can an insurance company compel a tobacco test of any sort?
My insurance company has a disclosure I must make that I am not a smoker: I am not a smoker, so no problem. But I'm wondering why anyone would ever say that they are a smoker? Shy of being seen smoking more than four times a week at work how could this be enforced? How could they ever conclude you wrongfully classified yourself as a non-smoker?
Can they compel a medical test of some sort?

I assume this is medical or life insurance. If the smoker never gets an illness closely associated with smoking (e.g. lung cancer), they'll probably get away with this.
But if they get lung cancer, and they try to get the insurance to cover the treatment (or death, if it's life insurance), it's likely that their smoking habit will come out. At this point, the insurance company may be able to refuse coverage due to lying on the application.
From What happens if you lie on your life insurance application?:

Lying on your life insurance application on purpose is considered fraud — also known as “material misrepresentation.” ... The insurer could cancel your application, you could make yourself uninsurable with other companies, and ultimately, you could leave your family without the financial protection they need when you’re gone.


I think this is conjecture and almost certainly wrong. But because I have insufficient information to follow-up with, I'm going to ask a follow up a question and loop back around to this.

How is it any different from any other question about committing a crime where it's hard to catch you? You might as well ask how the police can prohibit you from speeding when there's no cop on the highway?

BTW, I'm not saying this is a crime, just that it's like committing a crime that you can easily get away with.

https://law.stackexchange.com/q/106023/218

@EvanCarroll Deceiving your health insurance company in order to get benefits is pretty much the definition of insurance fraud.

@Barmar insurance fraud is in fact a crime in the US

usa texas

Can they compel a medical test of some sort?

Yes, and they routinely do. Insurers can condition coverage or premiums on tests if it is legally permissible. They can also condition it on questionnaires, where you'd need to provide the information yourself.
If the condition was permissible and you concealed it and lied on the relevant applications and questionnaires then see 18 USC 1035, related to health care benefits fraud, and potentially state statutes (e.g.: Texas Penal Code, Sec. 35 discussing insurance fraud).
Insurers are pretty good at investigating fraudulent claims and uncovering fraudulent applications since that's literally how they are making profit. They would rather deny a legitimate claim than pay a fraudulent one.

An insurer may require you to disclose your health conditions on applying for the insurance, when making a mid-term adjustment or noitifying them of a relevant change in your circumstances. This should be mentioned during the application process and in the policy documents. It is part of your contract with them.
This is routine in life insurance, health insurance and some travel insurance. The insurance premium (the price) is based on risks - different health conditions are associated with different risks. A history of smoking is usually associated with a relatively high risk.
When you make a health-related claim, they may ask you for your medical records. Refusal to disclose may give the insurer a valid reason to refuse to pay your claim. If you disclose your records and you are found to have misled the insurer this may give the insurer a valid reason to refuse to pay your claim.
So: yes, the insurer can require disclosure, if you want to buy insurance or if you want your insurer to pay your claim.
