Does HIPAA prevent your doctors from disclosing Protected Health Information with the insurance provider?
Is my doctor legally allowed to disclose personal health information to the insurance company?
Specifically, can the doctor say something on the lines of

"I believe this case of lung cancer is the result of smoking?"
Or, "The patient smokes"

To my health insurance company?

Certainly the later, at least.

HIPAA prevents the doctors from sharing protected information without proper authorization.
However as part of your agreeing to receive service from the doctor and providing insurance information as a payment guarantee you'd also be signing a page full of legalese. That legalese, among other things, means that you're giving your doctor an authorization to share any information with the insurance they'd need to share in order to get paid.
Specific conditions of this release depend on the actual legalese text you've signed, so you got to read that. But I have never been to any doctor in the US without signing such a waiver. Even in an ER they wouldn't start talking to me unless I signed it (I've never arrived to the ER unconscious, but have had a couple of visits where I wasn't completely dismembered and I had to sign a bunch of stuff before seeing even a nurse to take my temperature).
So if your expectation is that the insurer will pay for an illness closely associated with smoking when you told them you've never smoked and they won't ask any questions - you're about to get a very unpleasant surprise.

No, I wasn't expecting anything. I was just wondering whether or not HIPAA stoped your doctor from voluntarily disclosing PHI, and from this answer (which is pretty long just to say): "yes, but you likely waived that right in a rather standard form at your doctor's office."

@EvanCarroll yes, that was the first sentence.
